# losing csv data with deploying a discord bot - python

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, discord, discord.py

I working on a small discord bot(currently hosted on Heroku), one of the feature is a to-do list , currently I'm using a csv file as a to-do list. But whenever im deploying a new update the csv data is lost is there any way to not loose it? I'm also thinking of switching to a SQL Db if this csv thing doesn't work out.

Comment: If you switch to a SQL DB make sure it isn't something like sqlite. You need an external third party database server. As to your original CSV problem, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: csv, json files can't be stored on heroku permanently, so you need to switch to sqlite, mysql, postgresql or mongoDB